# angularJS returns to from state after successful transition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

From my register page I ultimately use `$state.go()` to redirect the user on a successful registration.

After the target state has successfully resolved its resolves, completely rendered, and been sitting there for ~500ms, the app is trying to return to the register state.

In HTML5 mode it seems to trigger a hard refresh where I can't catch the state change watching $stateChangeStart, when I'm not in HTML5 mode I can catch the event and prevent it, but this is clearly a hack.

Where should I look to track this down? I'm pretty lost. It doesn't seem there are any events being fired, and greping the codebase, there are 0 places that could be explicitly redirecting.

I'm using **angular 1.3.15**, and **ui-router 0.2.14**.

**EDIT**

please note, the catch in the resolve redirects to **LOGIN**, not **REGISTER**.

in the registration controller: `$state.go(Constants.STATE.INTRO, { allRec: 'all' });`

in the intro controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").config(function($stateProvider, Constants) {
    $stateProvider.state(Constants.STATE.INTRO, {
            url: "/intro/:allRec?query&category",
            views: {
                "grid@INTRO": {
                    templateUrl: "views/intro/layout.html",
                    controller: "IntroCtrl as intro"
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                introData: function(IntroService, $stateParams) {
                    return IntroService.getIntro()
                    .then(function(data) {
                        IntroService.getCount();
                        return data;
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        if (err && err.status && err.status === 401 || err.status === 500) {
                            $state.go(Constants.STATE.LOGIN);
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
    })
    .controller("IntroCtrl", IntroCtrl);
```

Comment: can you post some of your `$stateProvider` code, along with the actual state name in `$state.go('foo')`

Comment: the initial transition isn't an issue. it works every time and I've set break points in the catch which never get hit.

Comment: I forgot, it's also much more of a problem with html5 mode enabled since it seems to trigger a full page refresh instead of just transitioning to that state. Not sure if that's helpful or not.